# Pandas: Get values in column that have several different corresponding values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's take this sample dataframe :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','A','A','B','C','C','D','D'], 'Value':["6","2","1","1","2","2","3","2"]})

  Name Value
0    A     6
1    A     2
2    A     1
3    B     1
4    C     2
5    C     2
6    D     3
7    D     2
```

I would like to extract the values from Name that have at least 2 different values in Value column. I could of course use a for loop to check each value of df["Name"].unique() but it is very slow with my real big dataframe. Do you know an efficient way of doing this ?

Expected output :

```
[A,D]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-liner version using [`GroupBy.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) + [`query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) + [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_list.html?highlight=to_list#pandas.Index.to_list):

```
df.groupby('Name').nunique().query('Value > 1').index.to_list()
```

Result:

```
['A', 'D']
```

Answer (score 4):

Drop duplicates, `groupby`, and filter for groups of size 1.
Can you do that coding on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Prune comment :

```
df_gb = df.drop_duplicates().groupby("Name",as_index=False).agg({"Value":"count"})
list(df_gb[df_gb["Value"]>1]["Name"].values)
```

Output :

```
['A', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

Good, another option is using [GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) and [nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html?highlight=nunique#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique) method.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Name']).nunique()
list(df2[df2['Value'] > 1].index)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'D']
```